# Time complexity of recursive palindrome question, C++

Tags: c++, recursion, big-o

I was just wondering how I can find the time complexity of my recursive function here. I know that for the most part of my program its all in constant time O(1) but how do I calculate the time complexity of recursion functions as well.

```cpp
int pal(int n, int temp)
{
    // Using division of 10 trick
    if(n == 0)
        return temp;

    // Build the number backwards.
    temp = (temp * 10) + (n % 10);

    // Then advance through the number.
    return pal(n / 10, temp);
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5678;
    int temp = pal(n, 0);
    if(temp == n)
       cout << "Yes it is a palindrome";
    else
       cout << "No its not a palindrome";
]
```

Comment: recursion ≈ loop.  What is the complexity of a loop?

Comment: O(n) right? But is recursion any different from a loop?

Comment: This program has no inputs, so there's no variables to put in a big-O formula. The function `pal` does have a big-O formula in terms of its parameters, though.

Comment: What if I allowed the program to have input to the user?

Comment: *But is recursion any different from a loop* It is, but is also isn't.  All recursion can be replaced by a loop with a stack so in a very real way recursion is a loop, it just has special properties (each iteration of the loop has it's own local variables for instance)

Comment: If you call `D(n)` a function that returns the number of digits in an integer (ie: `D(5678) = 4`, `D(33) = 2`), then the runtime is `O(D(n))`, where n is the integer you're checking.

Comment: Note that for a given `n`, your `pal` calls itself with `n / 10`. Consequently, from that invocation it will once again call itself with `n / 100`, etc. The recursion stops once n is 0 which happens right after it was smaller than 10 on the previous call upstack.

Comment: Look at your input, how many times does it need to be divided by 10 until reaching 0? So you can get this division idea to make your loop that runs until the dividend equals 0.

Comment: recursion obviously has a `log_10(n)` depth, but there's no reason to write logarithmic base in O-notation, because `log_x(k) = (y/x)*log_y(k)` so that's just `O(log(n))`, where `n` is an input number (not length)

Answer (score 0):

It's `O(log(n))`, where n is the number.

But it's also `O(s)`, where s is the input size (pretty standard in computation theory to use input size as a string)

Compiled on any existing C++ platform, you could also argue it is `O(k)` because `int`'s have finite size.

So, it depends on the convention you use. Or whatever your professor showed in class. :-)